# Querying a MySQL database on a remote webserver through SSH

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

We have an internal MySQL database that our customer service department uses to do quotes, and an external MySQL database on our website that our customers use to do quotes.  I have a PHP report that I've written that gives me the information from the internal database.  Now I'd like to modify the report to include the data from the external database as well.  I need to connect to the external database by using a SSH connection.  I've been looking into using cURL or SSH2, but I'm not sure if either are the right way to do this.  Has anyone out there queried a SSH MySQL database on a webserver before, or does anyone know what I'd need to do to make this work?  Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Can you connect to the remote server's mysql port externally?  If so, you can just connect to their server just like you would any other mysql server.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking that I'd need to use the SSH2 code in PHP to do.  I haven't done that before, so I'm not sure if it will work.  I figured before I spent too much time figuring out if SSH2 is the way to go, I'd see if anyone had done something like this before and could point me in the right direction.  I had started off looking into cURL, but from what I saw, I don't think that will do what I need.  So far I'm thinking I'll have to try and connect to the database with SSH2 and then see if I can do my queries once I connect.

Comment: MySQL's connect protocol does allow it to be SSL encrypted. There'd be no need to use SSH and/or tunneling unless you don't want to expose the mysql port to the world: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

I actually use a MySQL GUI client called "Sequel Pro", which does offer the option to connect to MySQL through a SSH connection. This is totally doable, though if you have the option to connect to the DB without it (e.g. you can connect to it from "outside" the host), you should prefer this.

the easiest way I conceive you could query your DB through SSH is to use SSH port-forwarding, so you'd spawn a process that would do `ssh user@host-that-has-the-db -L3306:localhost:3306`, and then you'd have your MySQL connector connect on localhost.

The `-L` argument to SSH instructs it to do local port forwarding, so SSH will listen on a local port and forward what it receives there directly to the specified remote host/port from the other end. obviously my example uses port 3306 on both ends, but that can be changed as appropriate (RTM to have more about this)

Comment: So I would spawn that process on the webserver, correct?  Our website is hosted, and the provider isn't the most helpful when it comes to doing something like this.  Is this the only way to make it work, or is there another way?  I should state that I can log into the database remotely by using Navicat...I'm just trying to find a way to do it from inside my PHP code.  Thanks!

Comment: @kheugel Yes, SSH would be server-side. How do you do through Navicat? Does it do the SSH tunelling for you? If you can't spawn `ssh` nor use the `OpenSSH` API from within your PHP, then you'll be out of luck, and you'll have to resort to getting the data some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can query mysql from bash over SSH but this is not the best and scalable way to go. The best solution would be to create a REST Web Service on the production servers. Then your internal system will query that remote service with authentication.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Maybe there is infinite number of doing this, old & new ways, however I did a fast google for something simple to start with, I got this: http://robertobartolome.com/a-simple-web-service-using-php-json-and-mysql/ https://github.com/memaker/webservice-php-json , the code is just an example to get your started.

Answer (score 0):

You set up a tunnel from some available port on the  local server to the mysql port on the remote server:

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 someuser@remoteserver
```

That creates a tunnel listening on port 3307 on the local system, which connects to port 3306 (MySQL) on the remoteserver.

Then point your PHP code to connect to port 3307 instead of 3306 , and it'll get tunneled to mysql on the remoteserver.